# CLLocationCoordinate2D can't be instantiated

Tags: swift, runtime, core-location, cllocationcoordinate2d

I am trying to create some "CLLocation"s from data that I've read from a file. The first step is to instantiate a "CLLocationCoordinate2D" to be fed into the initializer for CLLocation. I'm trying out my ideas in a Playground and this very simple code generates a runtime error:

```
import CoreLocation

let lat = 48.8
let lon = -122.3
let point2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
```

Error message is

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.
```

I am pretty new to Swift programming and I have no idea what to do with any of this. E.g., how do I "use "thread return -x" " to do anything
Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

[I've tried to attach a picture of the whole playground but can't tell if that is possible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynmWv.png)

Comment: its not crashing here sir .. i double check it in playground ... are you using xcode ?

Comment: Weirdly, I'm getting the same crash on my Xcode-playgrounds too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankenstein was right - it must be an Xcode bug. I put the same code in a "real" program and no problem.

Answer (score 12):

Just happened to me. Try to replace `import CoreLocation` with `import MapKit` that's worked in mу case.