# why can't I use Core Location in a playground

Tags: xcode, core-location, swift-playground

In an Xcode Playground, we crash as soon as I try to use any Core Location types. I understand that actually trying to get a location would be asynchronous, but all I'm trying to do here is make a struct:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
let c = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 45, longitude: 45)
```

That crashes on the last line (the only executable line):

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.
```

Why?

(I've tried this in Xcode 11.7 and Xcode 12.2.)

Comment: Same in Xcode 11.3.1

Comment: I don't know the exact reason behind it so I don't write an answer only a comment, but in case somebody needs a solution: if you change CoreLocation to MapKit, it works, see here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64384130/8658561)

Comment: @jasond Thanks, that precedes my question so I'll close mine as a duplicate.